# Copy paste emails in bootstrap tokenfield not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tokenfield

Copy paste emails in bootstrap token-field not working in IE..

I am using bootstrap tokenfield and in **IE Browser** When i copy and paste set of emails only first email is viewed. Help me out to find a solution for this issue.

Comment: How about adding a paste button and then manually parse the clipboard and paste it in.